Mysql query to get more filtered data
We have following table in mysql



Column Name
Data Type




id
int(11)


price
int(11)


subject
varchar(63)


author
varchar(172)


class
varchar(3)


publisher
varchar(8)


region
int(11)



Sample Data



id
price
subject
author
class
publisher
region




1
350
Mathematics
John Doe
101
Alpha
1


2
420
English
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1


3
200
Mathematics
John Doe
101
Alpha
1


4
150
Science
Emma Brown
101
Alpha
2


5
280
Geography
David Wilson
102
Beta
1


6
300
Physics
Emma Brown
101
Alpha
2


7
220
Art
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1


8
190
Biology
David Wilson
103
Gamma
3


9
250
Chemistry
John Doe
101
Alpha
2


10
400
Philosophy
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1



Output Now we want output something like this using mysql query (in sort, we want to find costly book for each subject, each author, each class, each publisher and each region)



Subject
Author
Class
Publisher
Region
Highest Price




Mathematics
John Doe
101
Alpha
1
350


English
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1
420


Science
Emma Brown
101
Alpha
2
150


Geography
David Wilson
102
Beta
1
280


Physics
Emma Brown
101
Alpha
2
300


Art
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1
220


Biology
David Wilson
103
Gamma
3
190


Chemistry
John Doe
101
Alpha
2
250


Philosophy
Alice Johnson
102
Beta
1
400



What is the mysql query we can run to achieve this, here is the query we have written but that is not working(not giving the desired result)!
SELECT 
    subject, 
    author, 
    class, 
    publisher, 
    region, 
    MAX(price) AS highest_price
FROM 
    your_table_name
GROUP BY 
    subject, 
    author, 
    class, 
    publisher, 
    region;


"best mysql query" is asking for an opinion, and "is not working" is too vague to ask about on stackoverflow.  Please share details!

@Luuk added in the question only, where i've provided the sample data as well as desired output we want!

so I have to copy all data and test to see how your desired result differs from the current result?

in sort, we want to find costly book for each subject, each author, each class, each pulisher and each region

How are the results from this dbfiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/nfGwmXkn) different from the desired results?

@Luuk thank you very much buddy, you solved a huge issue for us!

You can try it:
 SELECT 
        subject, 
        author, 
        class, 
        publisher, 
        region, 
        MAX(price) AS highest_price
    FROM 
        your_table_name
    GROUP BY 
        subject, 
        author, 
        class, 
        publisher, 
        region
    HAVING 
        MAX(price) = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM your_table_name);

Because you use GROUP BY so you need to use HAVING to filter

As an official answer for this question, the explanation of "You can try it" does not give any useful information about this question.  You need to update your question to explain why you think this is the answer and how it works.
